# Can you merge multiple .indd files into one editable .indd without using book?

Tags: adobe-indesign, book, document-setup, cc-2014

I was curious to know if it is possible to merge several `.indd` files into one master `.indd` file that can be editable and preserve all links and images?

I am familiar with the drag and drop method and it does work but attempting to drag and drop 20+ `.indd` files can become an issue and may cause an error.

I do know how to use the `File -> New -> Book`:

[image]

although I am not happy with having to click on each `.indd` file in the panel to open and edit.  So I ask, is there a way to create a master file either in `.indb` or `.indd` that will let you edit within one document?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, one can move/copy pages from one document to another.

- Open both documents
- Open the Pages palette
- select the pages you want to copy
- right/control-click on the selected Pages and select `Move Pages...`
- change Move to:'s pop-up menu to the desired destination, set the Destination: as needed
- `OK`

Repeat once for each document (no drag-drop) and you can have everything in a single .indd.

Please note that it's best not to unnecessarily combine things. Instead, just open up the Book file for a project, then open up all the sub-files and work on everything all at once. Xrefs, &c. will work faster with everything open.

There is of course a script for doing this:

http://kasyan.ho.com.ua/downloads/mass_combine_a_bunch_of_indd_files_into_one.zip

Comment: Thanks for the input and I was aware of this method per @Joonas.  I also am aware how to create a book, as stated in the question, I am looking to create one master file so I can edit as such instead of going into each `.indd` file.